# How to split td?

Tags: html, split, html-table, space

I'm trying to create a table with pictures and I want that on the first **tr**
the picture will be big and in the second they will be smaller in 50%.
how can I remove the space between them?

Html

```
<table class="photos" style="border-spacing: 0; border-width: 0; padding: 0 0; border-width: 0;  border: 1; width: 100%;" >
    <tr>
        <td><img src="Dad.jpg" alt="dad" /></td>
        <td><img src="gili.jpg" alt="gili" /></td>
        <td><img src="me2.jpg" alt="me" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <td><img src="Hotrack.jpg" alt="hotrack" /></td>
        <td><img src="shir.jpg" alt="shir" /></td>

        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Picture for illustration:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/osfwnnmxv/]

Comment: Don't use a table as a layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Split it into 2 tables:

```
<table class="photos" style="border-spacing: 0; border-width: 0; padding: 0 0; border-width: 0;  border: 1; width: 100%;" >
    <tr>
        <td><img src="Dad.jpg" alt="dad" /></td>
        <td><img src="gili.jpg" alt="gili" /></td>
        <td><img src="me2.jpg" alt="me" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="photos" style="border-spacing: 0; border-width: 0; padding: 0 0; border-width: 0;  border: 1; width: 100%;" >
    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <td><img src="Hotrack.jpg" alt="hotrack" /></td>
        <td><img src="shir.jpg" alt="shir" /></td>

        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As SeaSarp said, do not use tables. You can use the `ul` and `li` elements instead. To archive what you want, you can create two lists (one for every line) and put the images in each `li`. Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://image_url" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://image_url" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://image_url" />
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://image_url" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://image_url" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://image_url" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://image_url" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://image_url" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://image_url" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

By default the lists have a vertical layout and some other particulars, you can change it using css:

```
ul {
    list-style:none; /* Do not show list points */
    display: flex; /* All elements together */
}

ul li {
    display:inline-block; /* All elements inline */
}
```

### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xe9a1ev9/